# Trouble getting DEFLATE working on Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, compression

I discovered that my server isn't serving up compressed pages.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230202/apache-addoutputfilterbytype-is-deprecated-how-to-rewrite-using-mod-filter), I added the following to my httpd conf file:

```
# Declare a "gzip" filter, it should run after all internal filters like PHP or SSI
FilterDeclare  gzip CONTENT_SET

# "gzip" filter can change "Content-Length", can not be used with range requests
FilterProtocol gzip change=yes;byteranges=no

# Enable "gzip" filter if "Content-Type" contains "text/html", "text/css" etc.
FilterProvider gzip DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
FilterProvider gzip DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
FilterProvider gzip DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/javascript
FilterProvider gzip DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
FilterProvider gzip DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-javascript

# Add "gzip" filter to the chain of filters
FilterChain    gzip
```

Next, I issued

```
apachectl configtest
```

which yielded this error:

> Invalid command 'FilterDeclare', perhaps misspelled or defined by a
>   module not included in the server configuration

Here's output from `httpd -l`

```
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
```

What module(s) do I need to install to get page compression working?  I am running CentOS 6.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Centos `mod_filter` are not loaded by default, you need add or uncomment in your `httpd.conf` the following line:

```
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
```

Don't forget reload your changes

```
service httpd graceful
```